# Change the order of an object

Tags: vue.js

I have an array composed by some objects and i want to filter the result by one of the properties.

This is the object:

```
  computed: {
starfleet() {
  const array = [
    {id: 1, order: 10},
    {id: 2, order: 9},
    {id: 3, order: 8},
    {id: 4, order:7}
  ]
```

I use a function methods to try to change the order:

```
  methods: {
superTab(starfleet) {
  return starfleet.orderBy(starfleet, 'order', 'asc');
},
```

In the template, i use an iteration:

```
<div v-for="item in superTab" :key="item.order">
          {{ item.id }}/{{ item.order }}
        </div>
```

Can you tell me why it doesn't work?

Thanks for your help

Comment: On a related note, I recommend giving your 'array' variable a more meaningful name.  It may work but could be confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not define data in `computed`. Do it in `data`.

You should use `computed` to return data in any other form than how it is in data, a sorted array is a perfect example.

`:key` should have an unique value. `:key="item.id"` might be better.

```js
<template>
  <div v-for="item in superTab" :key="item.id">
    {{ item.id }}/{{ item.order }}
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { defineComponent } from "vue";
export default defineComponent({
  data() {
    return {
      starfleet: [
        { id: 1, order: 10 },
        { id: 2, order: 9 },
        { id: 3, order: 8 },
        { id: 4, order: 7 },
      ],
    };
  },
  computed: {
    superTab() {
      return this.starfleet.sort((a, b) => a.order - b.order);
    },
  },
});
</script>
```

[Vue SFC Playground](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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)

Comment: i understand the problem thank you for your help @tauzN  ;)
When you use :key and the value is not unique, i had an error message but is it still possible to do it?

Comment: @KipoCTO The id's should be unique. Else you can do this: `<div v-for="(item, key) in superTab" :key="key">`

Answer (score 0):

Please first try

```
computed: {
starfleet() {
  const array = [
    {id: 1, order: 10},
    {id: 2, order: 9},
    {id: 3, order: 8},
    {id: 4, order:7}
  ]
return array
}
```

Rewrite superTab like below

```
superTab() {
  return this.starfleet.orderBy(starfleet, 'order', 'asc');
},
```

Comment: i just try it, i change superTab because starfleet was not defined, the error was:


error  'starfleet' is not defined  no-undef

so i use this code instead: 


superTab() {
  console.log("Hello world")
  return this.starfleet.orderBy(this.starfleet, 'order', 'asc');
},

What is strange is that console.log didn't show up even if i did the iteration in the template.